# Get public id of an image to delete

Tags: php, laravel, cloudinary

I upload images to `cloudinary` using `upload` method:

```
    public function store(StoreProductRequest $request)
    {
     
        $name = cloudinary()->upload($request->file('image')->getRealPath())->getSecurePath();
        Product::create([
             ...
            "imageUrl" => $name,
        ]);
    }
```

This will save the image cloudinary URL in `imageUrl` field, in `update` method, I want to get the public ID of the image of the product being updated if present:

```
    public function update(UpdateProductRequest $request, Product $product)
    {
        $imagePublicId = ??;
        if($request->input('image')){
           Cloudinary::destroy($imagePublicId);
        }
        ...
    }
```

How to get the public ID of the image and delete it?

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what package are you using to provide this functionality for cloudinary?

Comment: Thanks, ```cloudinary-labs/cloudinary-laravel```.

Comment: without looking at the documentation, i would imagine the object returned from the call to `upload` has a way to get the 'id' from it, just as you get the 'secure path' from it ... `getPublicId()` perhaps

Comment: i had to use method ```storeOnCloudinary``` instead of ```upload``` method, this will give you access to method ```getPublicId()``` on the uploaded image, then you can store that public id in the database.

Comment: `cloudinary()->getPublicId()` after you called `cloudinary()->upload(...)` would have gotten you the ID as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the official documentation for the upload response [here](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#upload_response)

You can get `public_id`, `asset_id`, and more.
You just have to get the response first like this

```
$response = cloudinary()->upload($request->file('image')->getRealPath());
```

and use the response to get the `SecurePath` and `PublicID`.

Apart from that, I have another solution that can be helpful to you check this [GitHub thread](https://github.com/cloudinary-community/cloudinary-laravel/issues/40#issuecomment-863496768)

Which says call `cloudinary()->getPublicId()` after `cloudinary()->upload(....)` like this

```
$name = cloudinary()->upload($request->file('image')->getRealPath())->getSecurePath();
$public_id = cloudinary()->getPublicId();
```